# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

Здравствуйте. Есть файл `DataBaseUtils.js` а в нем есть функция:

```
export function listNotes() {
  couch.get(dbName, viewUrl).then(
  (data, headers, status) => {
    console.log('Data was get!');
    return data.data.rows;
  },
  (err) => {
   console.log("Error in DataBaseUtils.js with listNotes()");
   return err;
  }
 );
};
```

Так же есть файл `app.js` в котором эта функция вызываеться следующим образом:

```
import * as db from 'utils/DataBaseUtils.js';

app.get('/notes', (req, res) => {
    db.listNotes().then(data => res.send(data));
});
```

Но при загрузке получаю следующее:

```
Server is up and running on port 8079
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
  at /Users/macuser/web/Notes/notes-app/server/app.js:13:17
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/macuser/web/Notes/notes-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at next (/Users/macuser/web/Notes/notes-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
  at Route.dispatch (/Users/macuser/web/Notes/notes-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/macuser/web/Notes/notes-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at /Users/macuser/web/Notes/notes-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
  at Function.process_params (/Users/macuser/web/Notes/notes-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
  at next (/Users/macuser/web/Notes/notes-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
  at jsonParser (/Users/macuser/web/Notes/notes-app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:109:7)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/macuser/web/Notes/notes-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
Data was get!
```

То есть функция работает. Потому что в последней строке написано `Data was get!`, но `return` не сработал.

При этом если внутри `listNotes()` заместо `return data.data.rows` написать `console.log(data.data.rows);` а потом в `app.js` вызвать функцию `db.listNotes()` то в консоль все данные из БД приходят.

Так же если в `app.js` написать так:

```
let data = db.listNotes();
console.log(data);
```

То в консоль приходит:

```
Server is up and running on port 8079
undefined
Data was get!
```

Вопрос: как мне получить из `listNotes()` данные, и почему я получаю `underfind` если в `listNotes()` они приходят?

Решение!
Спасибо @Grundy
Надо было просто добавить еще один `return` в `listNotes()` вот так:

```
export function listNotes() {
 return couch.get(dbName, viewUrl).then(....
```

Comment: забыл `return`.

Comment: Где я его забыл? Просто данные возвращает `listNotes()` а `return` там целых два, один с данными, а другой с ошибками

Comment: Смотри вопрос дубликат, там та же самая ошибка. внутри функции `listNotes` у тебя нет ни одного `return`

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена.